# Image manipulation tools for tizen

Tags: image-processing, tizen, tizen-native-app

I have just started working on Tizen. I want to know is there any built in support or library for image manipulating like contrast,color,crop etc to develop native application in Tizen.

Comment: There's the [Imageutil class](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.native.apireference/classTizen_1_1Media_1_1ImageUtil.html), but it only contains a few methods right now. You're probably better off providing your own image manipulation routines, or use 3rd party libraries.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks :), Is there any libraries available ?

Answer (score 0):

After Tizen 2.3 you can use `Cairo` for modify or manipulate image.
You can find many samples and snippets with google search easily.
It's easy to control contrast, color, crop etc with `cairo`.

Additionaly `Cairo` in `Tizen` provide some additional function and not support some functions.
check the following document.

https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4.0/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__OPENSRC__CAIRO__FRAMEWORK.html

And refer this document for using `cairo` with `evas image object` in tizen native app.

https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-guides/native-application/graphics/cairo?langredirect=1